# How to make footer smaller on wordpress site

Tags: css, wordpress, footer

Hello there im having an issue where the footer size seems to be really big, ive checked the theme settings in WP and it doesn't appear to have anything related to footer inside of it, so it might be something to do with the CSS here is a screenshot of the entire footer

http://puu.sh/gw0pt/35a2d4a28b.png

Comment: http://pastebin.com/b6u6HDT3 this is the CSS

Comment: 5,000 lines? Yeah i'm not going to read that. Filter out the parts which are specific to your example http://sscce.org/

Comment: Your footer has the height of the elements inside, plus the bottom paddings of the widget elements. Also we can't inspect anything from the picture and just pure css and speculate on that.

Seeign how this is themeforest theme, if you bought it, see if they have the support and if they can help you (theme authors, not themeforest).

Answer (score 1):

footer {font-size:14px;font-weight:400;font-style:normal;font-family:inherit}

search this part in css and
add in this part

height: what ever size you want in px;

Comment: cant find this in my CSS

Comment: Please write this code in your css

footer{height:what ever size you want in px;}